# Tengo un problema con PDO en PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo un problema con la última linea que me da el error indicado en el titulo de esta pregunta. Con el 'execute' de IdCompra.

He comprobado que no es un error de tipeo pero no veo que puede ser. Soy novato y soy consciente de que tal vez sea algo fácil, pero ¿Alguien sabe cuál es el error?

```
$id_transaccion = isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : '0';

$error = '';
if($id_transaccion == '') {
    $error = 'Error al procesar la petición';
} else {

    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM compra WHERE id_transaccion=? AND status=?");
          $sql->execute([$id_transaccion, 'COMPLETED']);
          if ($sql->fetchColumn() > 0) {
              
              $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT id, fecha, email, total FROM compra WHERE id_transaccion=? AND status=? LIMIT 1");
              $sql->execute([$id_transaccion, 'COMPLETED']);
              $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

              $idCompra = $row['id'];
              $total = $row['total'];
              $fecha = $row['fecha'];

              $sqlDet = $con->prepare("SELECT nombre, precio, cantidad FROM detalle_compra WHERE id_compra = ?");
              $sql->execute([$idCompra]);
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba cambiando `[$idCompra]` a `array($idCompra)`.

Answer (score 0):

En la exposición de la pregunta nunca indicas cuál es el error, para futuras preguntas considera agregar el mensaje de error como texto.

Dicho eso, estás haciendo **tres consultas** con el coste que ello supone, cuando puedes hacer sólo una. Se trataría de hacer una consulta que una las tablas `compra` y `detalle_compra` trayendo aquellas columnas que necesites.

La consulta sería esta:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.total, 
    c.fecha 
FROM compra AS c 
    INNER JOIN detalle_compra AS dc 
    ON c.id=dc.id_compra 
WHERE c.id_transaccion=? AND c.status=?
```

Aplicado en el código quedaría así:

```
$id_transaccion = isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : '0';

$error = '';
if($id_transaccion == '') {
    $error = 'Error al procesar la petición';
} else {
    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT c.id, c.total, c.fecha FROM compra AS c INNER JOIN detalle_compra AS dc ON c.id=dc.id_compra WHERE c.id_transaccion=? AND c.status=?");
    $sql->execute([$id_transaccion, 'COMPLETED']);
    # Con esto verificamos si hay filas
    if ( $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $idCompra = $row['id'];
        $total = $row['total'];
        $fecha = $row['fecha'];
        # No queda claro en tu lógica qué sigue aquí ¿?
    } else {
        $error='No se encontraron filas';
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, no se entiende el sentido de esta última consulta:

```
SELECT nombre, precio, cantidad FROM detalle_compra WHERE id_compra = ?
```

Pero, si necesitaras por algún motivo también esas columnas, sólo tienes que agregarlas al `SELECT` que indico al principio, algo así:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.total, 
    c.fecha,
    dc.nombre,
    dc.precio,
    dc.cantidad 
FROM compra AS c 
    INNER JOIN detalle_compra AS dc 
    ON c.id=dc.id_compra 
WHERE c.id_transaccion=? AND c.status=?
```